# How can annotations be added to dynamic proxy classes in Java?

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to create a dynamic proxy that would wrap an EJB around a web service because the application server does not support creating an EJB based web service without a proprietary router project generation.

My thought was to create a dynamic proxy, and some how just start it using an InitServlet.  Right now I am kind of stuck on figuring out how to set the annotations dynamically so that I won't get the following error.

```
class $Proxy0 has neither @WebSerivce nor @WebServiceProvider annotation
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.verifyImplementorClass(EndpointFactory.java:277)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.getPrimaryWsdl(EndpointImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:213)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:143)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I have had the same problem. It seems that most people say is not possible. See http://softwarecarnival.blogspot.be/2009/02/java-annotations-and-proxies.html

If the interface that you have is:

```
interface XXXInterface{
    Result doStuff1(String param1)
}
```

then a workaround is to create a delegator to the proxy that will also implement the web service.

```
@WebService
public class WebServiceDelegateToXXXServer implements XXXInterface{

   public WebServiceDelegateToXXXServer(XXXInterface actualImplementor){
       this.actualImplementor = actualImplementor;
   }

   public Result doStuff1(String param1){
       return actualImplementor.doStuff1(param1);
   }
}
```

Then you will publish

```
XXXInterface proxy = createProxyAsXXXInterface();
Endpoint.publish(url, new WebServiceDelegateToXXXServer(proxy));
```